# how to address datetime fields from SQL backend in Access front end?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ms-access, vba

I've used SSMA to migrate my access backend to SQL Server 2014. I've updated all my forms, queries and reports to work with SQL. I knew from the beginning that the datetime was showing up wrong in all of the forms (my users only wish to store date, not date AND time) and I assumed I'd easily be able to address the issue later on from the Access FE.

Now that I'm reaching the end of the project I haven't been able to find an easy way to convert the fields in the forms and reports to only show the date instead of the date AND time as its stored in SQL.

One thing I've tried that works, at least with a few reports that are based on SQL views (which I have in access as a linked table) is modify the view to convert the date e.g. `convert(varchar,StartDate,101) as StartDate`

Is there anyway to easily convert the DateTime (`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`) fields from SQL to show up in access as just Date (`mm/dd/yyyy`)?

Comment: Did you try `cast(StartDate as date)` in the view?

Comment: @Mat'sMug He might not want to or be able to change the SQL view itself, in which case the forms just need a format function: `format("2016-12-09 08:40:20", "yyyy-mm-dd")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to set the *Format* property of the textbox holding the date value:

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

or simply `Short Date` which, however, is localized.

This, of course, only works if your data type in SQL Server is *DateTime*, not *DateTime2* which the ODBC driver returns as text.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys.  I tried your suggestion @Gustav and it didn't appear to make a difference.  in the format property of a random date text box I tried "mm/dd/yyyy" as well as the "short date" setting and they both resulted in the date and time still showing.  In fact slightly worse since now it seems its right justified so that just the time is visible until you select left ( couldn't get ctrl+i to work to insert an image...)  I am using ODBC with "SQL Server" for the driver.

Comment: I also felt it important to note that casting won't help for forms that are based off of a table.  I would hate to have to create a view for every form that displays a date!

Comment: If the "dates" won't format, they are text, meaning that you most likely have defined the field in SQL Server as _DateTime2_ and not _DateTime_. You will have to correct this or anywhere in your application you will have to convert between Date and Text and viceversa. Not fun.

Comment: Ahh crud, well I didn't explicitly define them, SSMA I believe would have done that...  I'm checking now.

Comment: DANG! You're right!!! I didn't even catch that, they're ALL DateTime2, NOO!!!!!!!!!!  Time to put my head down...  Thanks for the help

Comment: Easy now, you are not the first hitting this.

Comment: Datetime2 will link as text column UNLESS you use the newer native 10 or 11 drivers with Access. If you using native 10/11 drivers, then the datetime2 columns WILL WORK just fine in Access. So either you re-migrate using SSMA and tell SSMA to use datetime as opposed to the newer datetime2 formats or you NOW adopt and install native 10/11 SQL drivers on each workstation. You can use older default legacy SQL driver and set SSMA to use datetime columns. Your choice either way, but when using SQL driver with datetime2, they appear as text columns to access unless you adopt the native 10/11 drivers

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal: Yes, install and use of the 11 driver should be the preferable option if permission is allowed.

Comment: Thanks again gustav and thanks @albert, I went with exactly your suggestion.  I changed the date "type mapping" in SSMA from datetime2 to just datetime, did another "convert, load and migrate" and that resolved my issue!  Had I known about the newer drivers I probably would have tried that first but saw your comment too late but at least I got my problem resolved.  Thanks again.